# automatically decrease container width while resizing broswer window

Tags: html, css

I am using CSS and HTML trying to reproduce the homepage of this website http://www.newsweek.com/ as an exercise.

If you open the page with a large screen you will see at both sides two empty columns that gradually decreases as the broswer width is reduced.

I want to reproduce this behaviour but can't make it until the end: I have set a container class with initial width 80% that become 100% at some point thanks to media query in CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1047px) {
    .container {
    width:100%;}}
```

What I miss is the gradually reduction of this container. How it can be made?

Thank you very much

Comment: Seems right so far, but we can't really say without seeing more of your code. Please post your HTML (at least a simplified version of it) and any other CSS you have related to the size and positioning of the container.

Comment: I've probably expressed myself badly. The code that I have posted it works, but I have no idea on how to reproduce the behaviour of the websites. My container suddenly (at 1047px) pass from 80% to 100%. What I would like, and I don't know how to do it, is to gradually pass from 80% to 100% as I reduce the broswer width (as done in the real website). Thanks!

Comment: They just have a max-width set on the content area too if you're referring to the grey sides/background area being reduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an experience like that, all you need is something like this:

```
.container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

If `.container` is applied to a block level element (like `<div>`) then this element naturally goes to be as wide as it can. This just says don't go wider than 1200px, and designate the left over space equally between the left and the right.

If for some reason the element is not block level (e.g. a `<span>`) then simply add `display: block;` to the above code to make it block level.